# getting a specific value from json data in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

Am having a callback url that returns json data in this format but i want to capture phone number only.How can I remove the body or metadata part or a way to capture this data in laravel:

```
{
   "Body":{
      "stkCallback":{
         "MerchantRequestID":"998",
         "CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_301120202034374244",
         "ResultCode":0,
         "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
         "CallbackMetadata":{
            "Item":[
               {
                  "Name":"Amount",
                  "Value":1
               },
               {
                  "Name":"ReceiptNumber",
                  "Value":"OKU"
               },
             
               
               {
                  "Name":"PhoneNumber",
                  "Value":934234
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is my code but does not return phone number:

```
$content=json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
 
        $phoneno=$content['PhoneNumber'];
```

Comment: It's the JSON you show the data after the json_decode?

Comment: @Maarten it is after json_decode . I get it from $response = json_decode($request->getContent());